# Internal Salesforce.com Error -- when I pass a Javascript value to Apex

Tags: apex, javascript, gack

Is there some Salesforce equivalent of https://jsfiddle.net/ ?  Here's the files involved.  I've pared them down to a simple case.

```
TestApp.app
<aura:application >
    <c:cltTest />
</aura:application>

cltTest.cmp
<aura:component controller="svrTestController"
        implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.initComponent}"/> 
</aura:component>

svrTestController.apxc
public with sharing class svrTestController {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static Integer doTest(String stringArgument, Integer integerArgument) {
        system.debug('stringArgument:');
        system.debug(stringArgument);
        system.debug('integerArgument:');
        system.debug(integerArgument);
        try {
            system.debug('stringArgument == \'cat\':');
            system.debug(stringArgument == 'cat');
            system.debug('integerArgument == 10:');  // line 11
            system.debug(integerArgument == 10);     // line 12
        } catch (Exception e) {
            system.debug('svrTestController caught exception.');
        } finally {
            system.debug('svrTestController is complete');
        }
        return 10;
        // If you don't return something, Salesforce thinks it's a constructor, 
        // and objects that constructors can't be static.
    }
}

cltTestController.js
({
    initComponent : function(cmp, event, helper) {
        helper.cltDoTest(cmp);
    }
})

cltTestHelper.js
({
    cltDoTest : function(cmp) {
        var action = cmp.get('c.doTest');
        action.setParams({
            stringArgument: 'cat', 
            integerArgument: 12
        });
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === 'SUCCESS') {
                console.log('Succeeded');
            } else {
                console.log('Failed');
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

When you run this, the log reads in part:

```
STATEMENT_EXECUTE      [11]|
USER_DEBUG             [11]|DEBUG|integerArgument == 10:
STATEMENT_EXECUTE      [12]|
FATAL_ERROR            Internal Salesforce.com Error
```

The helper calls the server-side controller with a Javascript number of 12.  The server-side controller interprets it as an Apex number.  And the mechanism blows.

(I've just realized that there are no integers on the Javascript side.  They are all "numbers", floating point quantities.  There's part of the problem.)

We suspect the answer is to tell the Apex side what to expect.  Something involving `<apex:attribute>`?

Comment: I followed the pattern here:  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_actions_call.htm   The example implies that it will also work if you define the <aura:attribute> in advance for a Double.  It doesn't.  It dies with an Internal Salesforce Error.  I will pass my parameters as strings, until light dawns.

Comment: You can use the Decimal data type, or you can use Integer.valueOf to sanitize the value.

Comment: It's extremely frustrating that this is still an issue almost 3 years since it was posted as a question on the dev forums in Oct. 2015: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000005FxqIAE

There are so many gotchas like this with Lightning it's very painful to work with.

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to go log a case. It appears that the internal state of the parameter is screwed up. Using parseInt in the helper does not fix the problem. Interestingly, if you use Integer.valueOf in your apex code, the problem goes away:

```
system.debug(Integer.valueOf(integerArgument) == 10);
```

Alternatively, use the Decimal type. Our limited ability to view the underlying data will probably make it impossible for us "outsiders" to fix the problem. I've suggested two workarounds here, but R&D really needs to know about this so they can issue a Known Issue and get it fixed.

---

Edit: Doing anything at all with the parameter that involves an operator causes the error. For example, I tried sanitizing by adding 0:

```
Integer integerArgument2 = integerArgument+0;
```

Same result; it crashed when I tried to add 0. You have to use Integer.valueOf before it starts working like a normal Integer should.

Comment: Thanks, sfdcfox!  I've asked my colleagues how I go about logging a case with Salesforce.

Comment: I created a case with Salesforce, and have my answer.  I don't find the answer very satisfying.  It amounts to:  1.  Cast it as a workaround.  2.  It will be fixed eventually.

Comment: I was hoping for "Yes, of course you can pass a number to a server-side controller.  Here's how to do it."

Comment: @user2171796 You can still use Decimal, though, so there is that.

Comment: In the sample code Nikunj sent me, the value passed in is typed Decimal, but it was still cast to Integer using valueOf, so I wasn't clear that it worked without casting if you typed the argument Decimal.  Yeah, I just tried it, and it worked, without casting.

Comment: I guess I don't understand what the Decimal type is.  If Javascript was passing an Int64 and Apex was treating it as an Int32, I would understand why it worked (on little-endian systems).  Do you have a picture in your mind of why Decimal works?

Comment: @user2171796 [Decimal is an arbitrary precision number](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apex_workbook.meta/apex_workbook/apex3_4.htm). Basically, it can store a number of any size. I presume that the parameters are passed over-the-wire as a JSON string, parsed by the AuraEnabled annotation, then fed in to your function. I'm guessing that the JSON parser in the annotation somehow manages to mangle the internal state of the Integer, but correctly populates a Decimal. Basically, two different code paths in the underlying system, one of which has a bug.

Comment: Ah!  A mental picture I can work with.  Bless you.